# How to count JSON log objects in logstash per user id matching 2 specific fields where one is a user id

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have JSON log objects of the format

```
{"consumerID":"1122233", "API":"/getWeatherData"}
{"consumerID":"1122233", "API":"/getTemperatureData"}
```

going into logstash.

I'm looking for a way to count the number of requests a user makes to each API and to make them available to my app so that I can display them on the frontend.

I need a way to generate log metrics per the consumerID field that is, count how many requests each user makes to each separate API and make that data available to my app.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I'm new to logstash, I don't know how to do this.